# In Django, what would be the proper way to persist session information?

Tags: django, session

I am designing a REST app in django, which I intend people to use without a browser (just direct API calls with curl or whatnot).  I have several different views where I want to pull in information about the session based on values that may have been a acquired from previous calls to other views.  It seems that every time a view is called the "request" object passed in is an entirely new session, so I'm wondering how I can persist values the "correct" way?

Example code:

```py
def login(request):
    ...
        ##I want to assign a token value to this session that is persisted to the entity requesting it
        request.session['token'] = response.json()['auth']
    ...
def grabSomeValues(request):
    ...
        ##I want to grab the session token value in here but of course the request object in the case is a completely new one that does not have that token value it seems
        print(request.session['token']
    ....
```

Comment: You can access the value assigned to the session variable:token in another view even if it new request. Also in the `login(request)` view did you check by printing the session variable just after the assignment.

Comment: yeah I can get the value after assignment in login, I actually have been debugging that by just returning the request.session['token'] value back to the user for now (I don't want to do this in the future and just hide it all server side if possible).  But then whenever I call grabSomeValues endpoint from same client, the request object retains none of the values that were set previously.

Comment: It should not happen you will get the session var value in `grabSomeValues(request)` function also. You are not getting means there may be some problem with your code. `request.session` just uses the existing session. May be your session is expiring soon that is why you are getting none.

Answer (score 0):

I think Middleware would help you.

> The session framework lets you store and retrieve arbitrary data on a per-site-visitor basis.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: I have the middleware enabled, I wouldn't be able to even use request.session otherwise.  My question is how am I supposed to actually use these session values between different views?  I set the request.session values, but every single time a new view is called the request object is completely new with no values saved from previous calls.